# Why can't i use contains within query function of pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to query based on a value within a column.

```
    #Following code works:
    {
      df_18.query("fuel == 6")
    }
    #but, all the following query throws error:
    {
     df_18.query("fuel.contains('6')")
     df_18.query("fuel.str.contains('6')")
    }
```

Please let me know what is the problem. Also Python documentation does not speak much about what is supported inside query function and what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can, using `python` engine:

```
In [36]: d
Out[36]:
  fuel
0   92
1   95
2   16
3   06

In [37]: d.query("fuel.str.contains('6')", engine='python')
Out[37]:
  fuel
2   16
3   06
```